# get key and value of second last element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array of undefined size, for example :

```
<?php
$array["foo"] = 86 ;
$array["bar"] = 49 ;
$array["matt"] = 96 ;
?>
```

i don't want to disturb array's internal pointer , but want to get a COPY of second last value of array instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, why you use a map, when in fact you want an ordered list instead, but

```
$tmp = array_values($array);
echo $tmp[count($tmp) -2];
```

should do it. With php5.4 this should work either

```
echo array_values($array)[count($array)-2];
```

Comment: use `array_keys($array)[count($array)-2];`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what size your array is planned for, so copying all values into a separate array might not be a good idea.

The following code slices out an array of length 1 just from the second last position and sets `$key` and `$value`.

```
$pair = array_slice($array, -2, 1, true);
$key = key($pair);
$value = current($pair);
```

PS: Should probably be put into a simple separated function?!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way.

```
$array["foo"] = 86 ;
$array["bar"] = 49 ;
$array["matt"] = 96 ;

$x = count($array);

foreach($array as $row)
{
    if($x == 2)
    { $secondLast = $row;}
    $x--; 
}
echo $secondLast;
```

Because you are using associative array.

Comment: using a loop for this would be very inefficient with large arrays